# How to add Hg installation option in multibranchPipelineJob?

Tags: jenkins, installation, mercurial, multibranch-pipeline

I want to add the mercurial installation option since it is not supported for multibranchPipelineJob in Jenkins. I thought of using the configure block, but it creates a new node "jenkins.branch.BranchSource" instead of updating the existing one.

```
configure {            
        (it / 'sources' / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' (plugin: 'branch-api@2.0.20') / 'source' / 'traits') <<  'hudson.plugins.mercurial.traits.MercurialInstallationSCMSourceTrait' {
            installation  'TortoiseHg-4.5.2-x64'
        }
    }
```

The resulted config.xml file is shown below:

```
<sources class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList">
    <data>
        <jenkins.branch.BranchSource plugin="branch-api@2.0.20">
            <source>
                <traits>
                    <hudson.plugins.mercurial.traits.MercurialInstallationSCMSourceTrait>
                        <installation>TortoiseHg-4.5.2-x64</installation>
                    </hudson.plugins.mercurial.traits.MercurialInstallationSCMSourceTrait>
                </traits>
            </source>
        </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        <jenkins.branch.BranchSource plugin="branch-api@2.0.20">
            <source plugin="mercurial@2.3" class="hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCMSource">
                <source>https://somerepopath</source>
                <credentialsId>username</credentialsId>
                <traits/>
            </source>
        </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
    </data>
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
</sources>
```

Anything I missed?

Jain.

Comment: It is the same issue as reported at the end of this post: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50177. I guess the author may have tried to fix it with configure block but no resolution posted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define a mercurial SCM source in the dsl format, the user can use the mercurialSCMSource method as provided by the DSL plugin to define credentials, source and id. Currently under this mercurialSCMSource method, you cannot define the Hg "installation". Hence one way to specify "installation" option was to use configure block.

When I used the configure block ONLY to define the "installation", it was creating 2 different "BranchSource" nodes as mentioned in the xml snapshot above. So another way to fix this issue was to use the configure block to define the entire mercurialSCMSource which includes credential, source and installation (which I needed). This way it generated the correct job (or config.xml)

NOTE: This fix also takes care of the "Append (<<) Not Working With Attributes" mentioned in this post: `https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block`

Hope it helps!!!

```
configure { project ->
    def node_base = (project / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' (plugin: 'branch-api@2.0.20') / 'source' (plugin: 'mercurial@2.3' , class: 'hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCMSource'))
    node_base << {
        source 'https://somerepolink'
        credentialsId 'username'
    }
    node_base << 'traits' {
        'hudson.plugins.mercurial.traits.MercurialInstallationSCMSourceTrait'{
            installation 'TortoiseHg-4.5.2-x64'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can add some explanation of what this fix means it would improve the answer.

Comment: @DaveInCaz added explanation